# Confusion around using a macro for an array length

Tags: arrays, c, macros, sizeof

This code below simply reads 10 integers and stores them in an array of length 10. I have two questions :

1. What is the difference in this example between using a macro `N ((int)(sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0])))` or simply an integer representing the length of the array (10 in this example) ?
2. Isn't a[0] called by `sizeof()` before being initialized ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N ((int)(sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0])))

int main(void)
{
    int a[10], i;

    printf("\nEnter %d numbers ", N);
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what `sizeof` cares about is the **type**. The type of `a[0]` is the same whether is has been initialized or not.

Comment: Aside: For this simple example, it would be easier to do `#define N 10` and `int a[N], i;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using casting to the type int is a bad idea. It is enough to write

```
#define N (sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]))
```

The value of a[0] is not used. The `sizeof` operator determines the type of the operand and then the size of an object of this type.

Pay attention to that `sizeof` is not a function. It is an operator.  You could also write

```
#define N (sizeof a / sizeof a[0] )
```

Using a magic number like 10 instead of the macro makes the program less flexible. If the number of elements in the array will be changed you will need to find all places where the magic number is used to update them.

Comment: So there is nothing more beneficial to using a macro other than flexibility ?

Comment: @alt72 It makes program more flexible, readable and less error prone.

Comment: _"less error prone"_?  Only _after_ macro has been properly verified.    But that aside, Macros can also make it more difficult to debug code that uses them.  Execution flow skips over content of macro when stepping through code.  For anything more than trivial macros, this can be a problem if it contains a bug.

Comment: @ryyker Macros are written once and used many times. So they are verified before their usages. Using magic numbers is very error prone. For example there can be a typo and instead of 10 there can be 11 or something else. Also you will be unable to say whether it is the number of elements in the array or of its subarray.

Comment: Still one thing, I don't understand why it is a bad idea to cast to type ```int```. I thought that ```sizeof``` returns some unsigned integer type (size_t) and without casting I'm comparing a signed integer ```i``` with an unsigned integer ```N``` which can result in weird behavior in some cases.

Comment: @alt72 The size of an object of the type int can be unable to store all values returned by the sizeof operator. So you should not use the casting.